# Kendo grid dados remoto XML

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, kendo-ui

Tenho um WCF que retorna os dados de um banco remoto MySQL, o retorno é um XML simples, acredito que por ser um XML simples não esta populando a minha grid kendo.

Gostaria de um exemplo para montar o meu XML de retorno e atender os requisitos da grid kendo, conforme o fornecido no exemplo da kendo grid: 
https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders

Answer (score 0):

Basta criar um DataSet, ler o arquivo XML em questão e adicionar a dataGrid

```
DataSet xml = new DataSet();

xml.ReadXml("XML");

GridView.DataSource = xml.Tables[0];
```